# getting issue while set up react native app with java 11

Tags: react-native

In my machine have the java 11 version. If I am running react native app, build getting failed .If I ran with java 8 version, build is getting succuss but I need run with java 11 also.
please help on this

Comment: Try to provide more information on this. What error do you get? Which OS are you using? I recommend you to follow the official documentation to set up your environment https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Pro OS. Ya, I followed the official document. If I am using the java8 version it's working but if I am using java 11 its not working